# Usage of the term "White Elephant" to mean something useless

Tags: idioms

A Thai restaurant near me is called the "White Elephant".

To me, choosing this name seems misguided: as far as I am concerned, a White Elephant is a useless item (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_elephant)). Is this usage just an English thing, or does it have the same connotations for other English speakers?

Comment: It seems to be a cultural thing. See [White elephant (animal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_elephant_%28animal%29#Thailand). Or just a business name they picked...

Comment: Because it's the name of a Thai restaurant, it has the connotation of "excellent" or "the best" (because "white elephant" or "albino elephant" (ช้างเผือก) is very rare). (I'm Thai.) There is more information about this as described on Wikipedia (under section Thailand). I can't say anything about other English speakers, though.

Comment: Thanks for that, @DamkerngT. I think that explains everything.

Comment: Yea, in Persian we say 'something is one's white elephant' we use it specifically when it concerns something useless that is costing too much. Think of a person who is admitted to a university, but after a while he notices that it's not what he wanted. However, he won't quit because he says to himself, "I've spent alot on this, can't let it go now!". It's even a very common expression in contexts related to business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely possible that the ownership were unaware of the connotations of the term "white elephant" in English—in other words, they may have been oblivious to the fact that they were, if not exactly shooting themselves in the foot, providing their would-be clientele with a reason to avoid their establishment or, at the very least, have a laugh at its expense.

In which case your assessment would be correct: that the name's use is misguided. That said, though, most native English speakers probably would not give the name a second thought. Only a small percentage of people (such as the ones who frequent boards like this one) would worry that the name of a Thai restaurant was awkward or inappropriate. A likely conversation:

> A: I don't feel like cooking tonight. Let's get some take-out (BrE: takeaway).
>   B: Fine with me. What do you feel like eating?
>   A: There's that new Thai place. Name is, like, Elephant something.
>   B: The White Elephant. Over on Cherry Street near the Shell station, I think.
>   A: Does that work for you?
>   B: Sure. Do they deliver?

Answer (score 1):

While it is true the phrase **White Elephant** has the meaning of a useless item, it is a term which people are already familiar with and so might find easy to remember. Audience familiarity (awareness) is one of the steps in a successful marketing campaign. It certainly is better than **Albino Pachyderm** or **Thai-m to Eat**.

A quick search showed that not only does your Thai restaurant in Carlisle, PA have the name, but there are several other businesses (not restaurants) which also use the name, so not everyone seems to be concerned with the literal meaning.

Is "White Elephant" worse than "[Cabbages and Condoms](http://hubpages.com/travel/Condom-Compendium-Review-of-Cabbages-Condoms-Restaurant-Bangkok-Thailand)"?